# how to fill generated odd number in new array java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I was given an assignment to create a array which generates 1000 random numbers, finds odd numbers then prints odd numbers. Then those generated odd numbers should be filled in a new array, say that, we have to create another array. One array captures 1000 arrays whilst printing only odd numbers. Then create second array which holds those generated odd numbers. Hers what i have written so far. I have problem. When a user enters 5 numbers, it generates 5 numbers, but doesnt print odd numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter number : ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int[] t = new int[n];
        int i;
        // Loop to do Array 
        for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            t[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 999);
        }
        // Array which displays odd numbers 
        System.out.println("THese are the generated Odd numbers : ");
        for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(t[i]);
            t[i] = 2 * i + 1;
        }
        int array[] = new int[8];
        for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
            array[a] = a;
        }
    }

}
//so this code t[i] = 2 * i + 1; isnt the write place.
```

the output is as follows:
Please enter number : 5
THese are the generated Odd numbers : 
131
42
685
806
668

Comment: when i run the program, am getting unexpected results. just like as follows:

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: Trying to understand the requirement here, you want to generate 1000 random numbers & store them in one array. Out of that 1000 numbers, you want to find ODD numbers & store them in another array?

Comment: jeah, i wanna generate 1000 random numbers, find out the odd numbers and print it. Then when when you print odd numbers, store them in another array....Jeah, thats what i am really wanna. I am confused...Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of your requirement,

You want to generate `n` random numbers & store them in one array. Out of that `n` numbers, you want to find `ODD numbers` & store them in another array.

Here's what you can do -

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter number : ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int[] t = new int[n];
        int i;
        int j;
        int oddCount = 0;

        System.out.println("These are the generated numbers : ");
        // Loop to do Array
        for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            t[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 999);
            System.out.println(t[i]);
            if(t[i] % 2 != 0) {
                oddCount++;
            }
        }

        int oddNumbers[] = new int[oddCount];
        // Array which displays odd numbers
        System.out.println("These are the generated Odd numbers : ");
        for (i = 0, j=0; i < t.length; i++) {
            if(t[i] % 2 != 0) {
                oddNumbers[j++] = t[i];
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < oddNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(oddNumbers[i]);
        }
        int evenCount = n - oddCount;
        System.out.println("Even share - " + evenCount);
        double evenPercent = ((double)evenCount/n) * 100.0;
        System.out.println("Even percentage - " + evenPercent);
    }
}
```

Comment: @imaginarygirl12 it stores all ODD number in `oddNumbers` array. Please check. Array `t` stores all the numbers.

Comment: If you just want to find even numbers count, you can do ‘int evenCount = n - oddCount;’. That will give you even numbers share @imaginarygirl12

Comment: And for percentage of even numbers, ‘double evenPercent = (double)evenCount/n;’

Comment: @imaginarygirl12 As far as formatting goes, you can see Yazeen’s answer. Or else try by yourself. That’s how you will learn. :)

Comment: @imaginarygirl12 Updated the answer. Please mark it correct if that is what you were looking for. :)

Comment: Use System.out.print() instead of System.out.println() inside both the for loop.

Comment: Hallo gohil, even percentage is calculating wrongly...percentage is not accurate...can you please check it..

Comment: Please enter number : 3
These are the generated numbers : 
 572
 860 780  
These are the generated Odd numbers : 
  
Even share ist 3
Even percentage ist as follows 1.0

Comment: @imaginarygirl12 just multiply it by 100. Sorry, missed that part.

Comment: double evenPercent = (evenCount*100)/n;

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

   private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       print("Enter Number: ");
       int n = scanner.nextInt();
       int[] numbers = generateNumbers(n);

       print("This is the generated number list: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
       print("These are the generated odd numbers: " + getAllOdds(numbers));
   }

   /**
    * @param num that needs to be checked
    * @return true if odd
    */
   private static boolean isOdd(int num) {
       return Math.abs(num) % 2 != 0;
   }

   /**
    * @param times iteration count to generate numbers.
    * @return the number array.
    */
   private static int[] generateNumbers(int times) {
       // Your logic goes here
       int[] arr = new int[times]; // Array to hold

       for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
           arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
       }

       return arr;
   }

   /**
    * @param arr array that needs to be checked for even/odd
    * @return filtered odd number array.
    */
   private static String getAllOdds(int[] arr) {

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       for (int anArr : arr) {
           if (isOdd(anArr)) {
               sb.append(anArr).append(", ");
           }
       }

       return sb.toString();
   }

   /**
    * @param m prints the message to the console.
    */
   private static void print(String m) {
       System.out.println(m);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see you doing is filling t with random numbers.
Then you loop over t and just print every int in that array.

```
        System.out.println("THese are the generated Odd numbers : ");
                for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(t[i]);
                    t[i] = 2 * i + 1;
                }
```

so you don't really filter out the even ones.
What you do next is just change te int on that index by multiplying it and adding one, wich, as I understand it isn't really the question.
As I understand it you should fill an array with random numbers, and find all the uneven ones in that array and put them in another one. 
You could do a check with %
like:

```
    if (t[i]%2!=0){
        System.out.printf("%d%n", t[i]);          
    }
```

That way if t[i]/2 doesn't equal 0 (t[i] is uneven) you print it to console, there you can also put it into another array if you want that.

Hope it helps.